# How to capture whole Barcode value on Winform without using TextChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

When a barcode is scanned on form1, I make a call to database to get the item for this barcode and open form2 with pre-populated data.

If I use text changed event then it makes as many times as numbers in one barcode.

I cannot check length of the barcode as it may be different each time.

which event I should use to make only one call when Barcode is scanned?

I tried TextChanged, KeyPress, KeyDown events but they all are being called multiple times.

```
    private void txt_Barcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        GenerateInvoice gn = new GenerateInvoice();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Inventory WHERE Barcode = '" + txt_Barcode.Text + "' ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (DR1.Read())
        {
            gn.txt_Barcode.Text = dr["Barcode"].ToString();
            gn.txt_ProductName.Text = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
            gn.txt_Price.Text = dr["SellingPrice"].ToString();
            gn.txt_QTY.Text = 1.ToString();
            gn.txt_Total.Text = dr["SellingPrice"].ToString();

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I am open to use textbox to capture barcode on form1 (I will hide it on UI)

Comment: A barcode scanner sends an Enter key when the code is complete. Plus, most scanners can be configured to also send a prefix, a suffix or both along with the barcode (to identify the scanner that sent the barcode, for example). Use the KeyDown event. E.g., `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //( process) }`

Comment: Also, your code's sql side leaves a bit to be desired. Get rid of the hard-coded query, use parameterization, look into proper resource cleanup with `using()` blocks.

Comment: As you are using the barcode scanner like a keyboard and ideally only want to fire the event once you could look at this: (debouncing and throttling)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991367/difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing-a-function

Answer (score 6):

This is a result of the scanner in WedgeMode. basically it acts as a keyboard and every character scanned creates a text changed event.

There are many solves.

You could use an api supplied by the company you bought the scanner off, instead of wedgemode

However, a simple solve is to put a prefix and suffix (like the ascii codes, `STX` and `ETX` ) on the scanner (there are usually settings for this supplied by the scanner), that way you know when you have complete bar-code data.

When you see a valid barcode, then you make one event, not an event for each character scanned.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably see a few of my answers on this topic.

[Improve Barcode search in a Textbox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913924/improve-barcode-search-in-a-textbox-c-sharp)

[distinguish between the scanner and the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630962/distinguish-between-the-scanner-and-the-keyboard/5631487)

[Barcode scanner with a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193313/barcode-scanner-with-a-wpf-application)

If I was to do it again *and the first time was a long time ago*, I'd opt for RawInput's and determine which device is the BarCode scanner. Using prefix and suffix are reliable *although they vary depending on the device*. **Capturing the raw input abstracts this hardware implementation.**

Code Project article and download: [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)

See how I can get input from any source so I dont even need the user to put a cursor on a textbox or use `Form.KeyPreview` I can get the input filtered by device.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let the event wait for 1 second, or long enough to finish scanning

```
private async void txt_Barcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    con.Open();
    GenerateInvoice gn = new GenerateInvoice();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Inventory WHERE Barcode = '" + txt_Barcode.Text + "' ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    while (DR1.Read())
    {
        gn.txt_Barcode.Text = dr["Barcode"].ToString();
        gn.txt_ProductName.Text = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
        gn.txt_Price.Text = dr["SellingPrice"].ToString();
        gn.txt_QTY.Text = 1.ToString();
        gn.txt_Total.Text = dr["SellingPrice"].ToString();

    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: While this will work it will fire a dB call every text change event and sometimes the barcode input gets cut off, best to at least test the length of  txt_Barcode before the dB call.